# Django redirect to on-page link

Tags: javascript, django, hyperlink

FYI - development site, work in progress.

I am using Django on a page with a form.  However, I am also using a javascript tab function on this same page which highlights the tab with the correct on-page link / hash.

The default page = http://learntango.webfactional.com/video/35863752#section=comment
The contact-us page = http://learntango.webfactional.com/video/35863752#section=contact

When the form is not valid, the page is returned (good).  However, it is the base page which is returned: http://learntango.webfactional.com/video/35863752

After that, the javascript then defaults this to the comment page.

How do I return the same page, with the "contact" on-page link active, so they can see their form errors and realize that the form did not submit?

Thanks!
David

```
def video(request, url_vimeo_id):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = ContactForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            cd = form.cleaned_data
            send_mail(
                'This is an e-mail from the website',
                cd['message'],
                cd.get('email', 'noreply@example.com'),
                ['dwyliu@gmail.com'],
            )
            return HttpResponseRedirect('http://www.learntodancetango.com')
        return render_to_response('video.html',{'video': video,'next':next, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
    else:
        form = ContactForm()
        return render_to_response('video.html',{'video': video,'next':next, 'form': form}, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set form's `action` as `http://learntango.webfactional.com/video/35863752#section=contact`